# The set of points covered by a bouncing ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, puzzle

I wonder in which condition a bouncing ball can cover every point in the set $[0, 1]^2$.

**Problem statement:**

Given a straight line $l$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let
$$
C = \{(x - \lfloor x \rfloor, y - \lfloor y \rfloor) : (x, y) \in l\}
$$

In which condition $C$ is dense on $[0, 1]^2$ ?

In which condition $C = [0, 1]^2$ ?

**Some observations**

Let $l$ be parameterized by $y = ax + b$
By symmetry, we can limit the domain as $a \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$, $b \in [0, 1]$, and **possibly** $x \in [0, \infty)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$

- If $a$ is rational, $C \neq [0, 1]^2$
- If $a$ is irrational, $l$ goes through all vertical lines of the form $x = z$ for $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ at $y_z$. Then $\{y_z - \lfloor y_z \rfloor : z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is an infinite set, i.e. trajectory of the bouncing ball is infinitely long

Given Peano theorem, i.e the existence of space-filling curve. I am not sure how likely whether we have a definite answer to this.

Comment: The space-filling curves are considerably more complicated than your bouncing ball curves. Lines with irrational slope will be dense in the square. Pages 8 and 9 of https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1213210/FULLTEXT01.pdf may clear some things up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you sir

Comment: https://plus.maths.org/content/billiards-donuts also looks helpful.

Comment: $C=[0,1]^2$ is impossible because you have a countable union of sets of measure 0, which will itself have measure 0.

Comment: @Samuel great explanation